# Python 2 - ord() returning an incorrect value

Tags: python, utf-8, python-2.x, non-ascii-characters, ord

This is my text file (`sample.txt`).

```
É
Â
Ê
Î
Ç
Ô
È
Û
Ï
Ë
À
Ù
Ü
```

Now when I invoke python script to read the ord() values of those characters I always receive `195`. Why is that?

```
file = open("C:\sample.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    print ord(line[0])
file.close()
```

ord() value of `195` is this character: `Ã` and it is not present in any of the above-mentioned lines by me at all. I am expecting within an output of the following sequence for:

```
201, 194, 202, 206, 199, 212, 200, 219, 207, 203, 192, 217, 220.
```

Comment: Just an FYI, but python 2 is no longer supported, you should switch to python 3.

Comment: @Xilpex that probably helps -- with Python 3.7, `ord('É')` is 201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch to python 3; It fixes the problem:

```
file = open("sample.txt", "r")
for line in file:
    print(ord(line[0]))
file.close()
```

This prints:

```
201
194
202
206
199
212
200
219
207
203
192
217
220
```

Just like expected.

Comment: What if I am restricted to use only python 2? Does ord(line[1] + 64) do the task or is there some other flaw in that statement also? Well, let me know very well about this type of thing.

Comment: By the way, people please note that ord(line[0]) == 195 is another requirement check up before trying out the above mentioned type of thing, by making use of itself.

Comment: @V.Raman -- If you are restricted to python 2 (you shouldn't be), then you'll have to look into decoding the file. Try printing `line[0]`. It won't print it properly. You'll have to find the encoding, then decode it.